# deserialize json array in coldfusion

Tags: arrays, json, coldfusion

I need Help processing my myTableArray variable on the new2.cfm side; in which i tried many things but still failed to deserialize the JSON array. any ideas would be much appreciated. no the my count variable is just a counter from a query to make different functions for each table row. now clicking the button should take the data to new2.cfm, and there i should be able to edit the table with my sql and updating the data. however, i cant process the JSON data on that end. even when i sent it as a url still couldn't manipulate it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button.mybutton#mycount#").click(function(){
    //Create the main array
var myTableArray#mycount# = [];
$("table").each(function() {
 //trigger an array loop using .each
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td.mytd#mycount#');
    // assign values to data
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
        tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
        myTableArray#mycount#.push(arrayOfThisRow);
    }
});
var j = myTableArray#mycount#;
console.log(j);
$.ajax({
  // the location of the CFM to run
    url: "new2.cfm?json=" + j
  // pos data
  , type: "post"

  // send the data to the CFM
  , data: {
    // send the Array 
    j:j
  }
  // this gets the data returned on success
  , success: function (data){

    $(".myp").html(data);
  }
  // this runs if an error
  , error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // show error
    alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: When you follow the link without using AJAX do you get the results you are expecting? The the JSON have debug in it?

Comment: if you see i try to pass the information thru the URL in it works fine, then i get all the values with a cfloop. however, whenever i try to do gethttprequest.data i get the data but it doesnt allow me to deserialize it because its a string

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnt allow me to deserialize it because its a string" -- the input of `deserializeJson()` is a `string`.  Can you post an example of what you get in `getHttpRequest.data`?

Comment: my code on the receiving page is simple, I have: <cfset myvariable = gethttprequest.data()> and it says complex objects cannot be converted to simple values. then i tried toString(gethttprequest.data()) and it worked as i can cfdump the variable but i cant break it apart nor i can even loop through it because its a string.